# Method like windows() in rust but for javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a method in javascript that does the same thing as windows in rust?

I want to iterate over an array in js comparing 2 values each time like you can with windows() in rust but not sure if there is a method for this.

Anyone know a method or a similar way to recreate it?

`windows()` example:

```
let slice = ['r', 'u', 's', 't'];
let mut iter = slice.windows(2);
assert_eq!(iter.next().unwrap(), &['r', 'u']);
assert_eq!(iter.next().unwrap(), &['u', 's']);
assert_eq!(iter.next().unwrap(), &['s', 't']);
assert!(iter.next().is_none());
```

Comment: are you talking about `slice.windows()`?

Comment: Please provide an example of the `windows()` usage in `rust`.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes exactly.

@AlexN 
```
let slice = ['r', 'u', 's', 't'];
let mut iter = slice.windows(2);
assert_eq!(iter.next().unwrap(), &['r', 'u']);
assert_eq!(iter.next().unwrap(), &['u', 's']);
assert_eq!(iter.next().unwrap(), &['s', 't']);
assert!(iter.next().is_none());
```

Comment: @Cathal - please note I changed the code in the answer - a helpful person pointed out I made an error (I conflated `windows` and `chunks` docs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) function is a good fit for this

```js
function* windows(array, count=1) {
  if (typeof count !== 'number') {
    throw new Error("paramater must be a number");
  }
  let index = 0;
  while(index < array.length - count + 1) {
    yield array.slice(index, index+count);
    index++;
  }
}
const x = windows(['r', 'u', 's', 't'], 2);
[...x].forEach(v=>console.log(v))
```

Additionally, if you aren't averse to adding methods to built-in types

You can do it like this

```js
Array.prototype.windows = function*(count) {
  if (typeof count !== 'number') {
    throw new Error("paramater must be a number");
  }
  let index = 0;
  while(index < this.length - count + 1) {
    yield this.slice(index, index+count);
    index++;
  }
}
const array = ['r', 'u', 's', 't'];
[...array.windows(2)].forEach(v=>console.log(v))
```

This way, all Array's *just*  have the `windows` method

Additionally ... here's some naive code that mimics in part the code you have in the question

```js
Array.prototype.windows = function*(count) {
  if (typeof count !== 'number') {
    throw new Error("paramater must be a number");
  }
  let index = 0;
  while(index < this.length - count + 1) {
    yield this.slice(index, index+count);
    index++;
  }
}
const assert_eq = (a, b) => {
  a = a.toString();
  b = b.toString();
  if (a !== b) {
    throw "fail";
  }
  console.log('ok');
};

const slice = ['r', 'u', 's', 't'];
const iter = slice.windows(2);
assert_eq(iter.next().value, ['r', 'u']);
assert_eq(iter.next().value, ['u', 's']);
assert_eq(iter.next().value, ['s', 't']);
assert_eq(iter.next().done, true);
```

Bonus note: if you want to implement "chunks"

```
while(index < this.length) {
    yield this.slice(index, index+count);
    index+=count;
}
```

Comment: +1, although please [bear in mind](http://www.brainlesstales.com/images/2013/Jul/bear-in-mind.jpg) the `while` loop gets too far and so the last `yield`ed value(s) may be sth else than they would in Rust.

I think the loop should look more like this `while(index < array.length - count + 1)`.

Comment: @Przemyslaw sorry - I conflated `windows` with `chunks` - thank you - many thanks for your observations :p

Comment: @Przemyslaw - that link though ... :p bear in mind indeed

Comment: Haha, yeah, I just can't but picture this in my head every time I use this phrase :D. Glad to help. 